# Como efetivar uma inscrição no Moodle, e onde os dados são gravados?

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

Estou desenvolvendo um plugin de inscrição do Moodle o qual gera um boleto de determinado banco, mas tenho algumas dúvidas com relação a confirmação da inscrição do usuário (enrol):

Qual é a tabela responsável por inscrever um aluno a um curso no Moodle?

Qual seria o comando para efetivar a inscrição?

A documentação do Moodle é extremamente confusa, dificultando o trabalho do desenvolvedor.

Comment: Ninguém para ajudar?

Comment: Veja esses links abaixo. Acho que podem te dar o caminho. http://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.moodlemoot.com.br%2F2013%2Fmoodle%2Fmod%2Fresource%2Fview.php%3Fid%3D50&ei=pbO1VPnVGM61sQStm4CYCQ&usg=AFQjCNE0KM6iQqgMNpvLW0m72tiH9q8YHw&sig2=IjC0TMcj5OhppjBetmhJ_A&bvm=bv.83339334,d.cWc http://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDoQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fbadiu.net%2Fdownload%2Fmoodlemoot%2F20014_floripa%2Fmudanca_arquitetura_banco_moodle_2.ppt&ei=pbO1VPnVGM61sQStm4CYCQ&usg=AFQjCN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tabela padrão dos alunos é a `mdl_user`. A tabela onde tem o registro das matrículas é a `mdl_role_assignments`.

Para inserir um aluno, por exemplo, através do banco, você pode consultar [este arquivo](http://badiu.net/download/moodlemoot/20014_floripa/mudanca_arquitetura_banco_moodle_2.ppt), onde é explicada a estrutura SQL do Moodle.

[Neste artigo](http://moodlesql.blogspot.com.br/2010/07/matricular-usuario-no-curso-do-moodle.html) tem uma explicação mais detalhada de como inserir um aluno do Moodle em um novo curso, mas é baseado na versão 1.7.